# Number of files received by a file receive location

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-bam

Is there a way to calculate the number of files received by a receive location using BAM?

Answer (score 1):

Not really directly, unless you specifically created a metric for that on your observation model. BAM itself doesn't track that information otherwise, and things get a bit more complicated if you're doing debatching of messages in the receive pipeline (because then #messages != #files).

Comment: Yes, I am debatching messages in the receive pipeline. I thought may be I can use the ReceivedFileName from the FILE.bts_file_properties schema, but with no luck.

Comment: But do you have a BAM model at all? Or what exactly are you doing? BAM really doesn't do anything by itself. Depending on exactly what you want, it may be that BizTalk Tracking might be enough for your needs, or else, you might need a custom solution of sorts (which would be doable with a custom pipeline component)

Answer (score 0):

I use the API to come up with a list of every intersection of Orchestration and Receive Location and then report on 1) whether (and when) the file was picked up along with status of operation, and 2) whether (and when) the file went through orchestration along with status.  It's lots of code but do-able.  And of course as tomasr states if a file gets debatched into separate messages, the logic is only good for last message.

-Krip